# Applying simultaneous filters to datatable

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lightninginput, lightning-duallistbox

I have four LWC components: - A datatable that displays data - An input text field - A dual listbox - Another dual listbox

I need to make input field and both dual listbox work as simultaneous filters on my datatable. I can make every one run fine on its own but making it simultaneous is a little tricky.

i found this code on internet:

```
    this.data = this.records.filter(
    record => (record.First === this.firstValue)
    ).filter(
    record => (record.Second === this.secondValue)
    ).filter(
    record => (record.Third === this.thirdValue)
    );
```

but i dont know how could i make 2 things on the same event for every component: -Return event.detail.values (for every component to pass to its respective filter)onchange to apply to filter and also aplying all these filters onchange.

is there a way to use the same event for every component? Or how should i approach this problem? Just to clarify is for an excerise i need to complete. Thanks! Sorry if something is unclear im just starting in Salesforce

Comment: you can update  you question with more details with component strcture.there msut be a master component  which is listenig o your event.modify  the data   you are passing t the datatble  on each event listener. as each input will publish an event  you can fikter master data  in event handler

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.